# PyQT5 menu not visible

Tags: qt, menu, qt5, pyqt5

When executing this little PyQT5 script, I can't see the menu; it just displays an empty window (no errors or warnings) on ubuntu 14.04.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()
        self.createUI()

    def doAction(self):
        print('action')

    def createUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        menu   = self.menuBar().addMenu('File')
        action = menu.addAction('Action')
        action.triggered.connect(self.doAction)   


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    window.setGeometry(400, 200, 200, 200)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have tested it both Mac and Ubuntu and it shows for me when I run from the command line? Are you using an IDE of some sorts? If so, which?

Comment: I also start it from command line, but there is no menu bar visible.

Comment: It works for PyQT4 instead of PyQT5, so I'll use that for the moment. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I launched your code on Win 7, Python 3.4. I can see a window with File -> Action Menu.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem
Try to set native menu bar flag as false like this:

```
menu.setNativeMenuBar(False)
```

Comment: where menu = self.menuBar()